# Incorrect type of argument

Tags: c, kernel, opencl

I have a problem with my opencl program. I have a kernel with declaration like this:

```
__kernel doSmth(_write_only Image2d_t img)
{
      /*do magic*/
}
```

and I want to set an argument to this, like this:

```
cl_mem img = clCreateImage2D(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, &outFormat, width, height, 0, 0, &err);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&img);
```

But I'm getting error number -52 that I pass invalid type of arguments, I have no idea what I do wrong so if someone could help me I will be very grateful!

Comment: Looks correct to me. The error `-52` (`CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS`) usually means that arguments haven't been set at all. Is the `kernel` argument to your `clSetKernelArg` call *definitely* the same as the kernel you pass to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`? Can you show us more of the host code (e.g. from kernel creation, through to enqueue)?

Comment: @jprice I want to run correct version of this program: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999758/mandelbrot-set-using-opencl but I have a problem with error number -52